# Why wont IE fire on paste event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help figuring out why Internet Explorer won't fire my 'paste' event.

I'm using IE 11. Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('paste', '.pasteTarget', handlePaste);
```

When trying this in IE, the function never gets called. It works in chrome.

Comment: Does the console give you any errors?

Comment: And do you have to delegate, is `.pasteTarget` inserted dynamically.

Comment: @nicovank No console errors.

Comment: @adeneo .pasteTarget is a class on the form.

Comment: I get that, but why are you delegating, why not `$('.pasteTarget').on('paste'...`

Answer (score 2):

**Different browsers treat `onpaste` differently, or not at all.** For IE 11, the latter seems to be the case.

---

From MDN:

> **Non-Standard**
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste)

---

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, IE 11 does indeed support `onpaste` to some extent. However, as this is a non-standard feature, you should be careful about using it in production.

Comment: Got some resource saying IE 11 does not support it? IE has supported it in some capacity in the past.

Comment: Regardless, even if I used Ctrl+V, I don't think there is a way to access an image from the clipboard in IE. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Just tested it in IE 11, at least assigning an event handler to `document.body.onpaste` indeed seems to work. Nevertheless, [in Firefox the `onpaste` event seems to be completely unavailable](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard), so I think the basic point of my answer is still valid.

Comment: That's not it at all, in IE the `paste` event doesn't bubble, so delegation fails. It supports `onpaste` from IE9 and up.

Comment: @adeneo You could post that as an answer, or point us to a duplicate if you have one.

Comment: Firefox supports `onpaste` just fine, the link is for the clipBoard API, which has it's own `cut` and `paste` events.

Comment: Alright, I'm giving up. Worded it more generic, hope this covers it. Not really an answer to the question anymore, though...

Comment: Has an update been found for this? I cannot fire the onpaste event in IE11

Answer (score 0):

You could use `beforepaste` event instead and access `clipboardData` from `window`, not from the event. 
But, indeed as pointed out already, Clipboard API doesn't seem to be supported in IE: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/clipboardapi/