# Window paste Ctrl+V addEventListener not firing in IE 11 but firing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, typescript, window, clipboard, addeventlistener

This is my code that works perfectly in **chrome** browser

```
window.addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler); //chrome
```

The problem is in **IE11** browser when select `Ctrl+V` is never fired on the clipboard.

I have tried this without success

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    alert("firefox, chrome, etc");
    window.addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    alert("IE");
    window.attachEvent("paste", pasteHandler);
}
```

Why is that?

My code below

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cc");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (window.addEventListener) {
    alert("firefox, chrome, etc");
    window.addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    alert("IE");
    window.attachEvent("paste", pasteHandler);
}   

function pasteHandler(e) {
    if (e.clipboardData == false) return false; //empty
    var items = e.clipboardData.items;
    if (items == undefined) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) continue; //not image
        var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
        var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
        paste_createImage(source);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/clipboardapi/) not working

Comment: @Andreas sorry edit question in progress

Comment: And why do you think the event handler isn't called in case of IE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why wont IE fire on paste event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751786/why-wont-ie-fire-on-paste-event)

Comment: @ritaj your suggested link on question Why wont IE fire on paste event? not working https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/clipboardapi/

Comment: @Andreas because the CTRL+V not is added in clipboard

Comment: How did you determine that the event is not triggered and/or the event handler is not executed. Did you step through the code with the debugger? Did you add `console.log()`s in the different stages of your script?

Comment: @Andreas I need saving as image on the server using ASP.NET. This is the tutorial https://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1662/saving-html-5-canvas-as-image-on-the-server-using-aspnet. This tutorial work correctly in browser chrome but not in internet explorer.